# Given a positive int, finds out how many numbers # from 1 to n inclusive evenly divide n

Tags: python

The goal is to "find out how many numbers # from 1 to n inclusive evenly divide n" when given a positive int. Here is the code I have so far

```
def num_divisors(n):
    for i in n:
     if n >= 1:
        answer = i // n
     return answer
```

I'm currently getting the error `'int' object is not iterable` for all test cases and here they are for reference:

```
Check that num_divisors( 1 ) returns 1
Check that num_divisors( 12 ) returns 6
Check that num_divisors( 100 ) returns 9
Check that num_divisors( 360 ) returns 24.
```

Comment: Because you passing `int` object and trying to iterate it.

Comment: SO isn't going to do your homework... You may want to think about your loop and the condition under which it exits. Given you need to count the number of divisors you will need to find them all.

Comment: @AChampion this isn't exactly homework it is an exercise on an online coding program thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code is following

```
def num_divisors(n):
    count_d = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            count_d += 1
    return count_d
```

Comment: I chose this solution because it worked really well. @brianpck I think your code would work as well but I wasn't sure what to return and the program would just return None for each value. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(n):
```

This loops over all values from 0 to n-1

EDIT:

Your code is still flawed, and has other errors.  You should have an accumulator counting the number of values which divide `n`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that should do what you want:

```
sum(n % i == 0 for i in range(1, n + 1))
```

Issues with your code:

- Trying to iterate over an int, instead of an iterator.
- Floor-dividing `i` by `n`, which will always give you 0
- Returning `answer` at the end of each loop

Comment: Nice! You could add explanation that the sum works because `False` is 0 and `True` is 1.

Comment: Yes, though I personally don't like that hack, I would tend to write `sum(1 for i in range(1, n+1) if n%i == 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

This code reduces the number of divisions to approx. sqrt(n). For example if 100 == 4 x 25, then also 100 == 25 x 4, so after testing 4 we don't have to test 25.

```
def num_divisors(n):
    num = 0 
    for i in range(1, n + 1): 
       d, m = divmod(n, i)
       if d < i:
            break
       if m == 0:
            # n = d * i
            num += 1 if d == i else 2
    return num
```